# Get Value from Min and Max date in Power Bi - Group by

Tags: powerbi, dax, grouping, powerquery

I am working with a database of surgeries performed.

The database contains in each row the patient's id, date of surgery and surgery performed.

A patient can have more than one surgery and this surgery can be different.

What I am trying to obtain is the number of surgeries performed by each patient, what was the first surgery and the last surgery performed.

This is the original database example:

| patient | date | surgery | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01-01-22 | Eyes | 1 |
| B | 01-01-22 | Mouth | 2 |
| C | 01-01-22 | Nose | 3 |
| A | 01-05-22 | Mouth | 4 |
| C | 01-06-22 | Eyes | 5 |
| B | 01-07-22 | Mouth | 6 |
| A | 01-12-22 | Nose | 7 |

I need the following output:

| patient | number of surgeries | First Surgery | Last Surgery |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | Eyes | Nose |
| B | 2 | Mouth | Mouth |
| C | 2 | Nose | Eyes |

I'm using the following Dax's expression:

```
N_Surgery = GROUPBY(Surgery, Surgery[patient_id], 
                           "N_Surgery", COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP(), Surgery[id]))
```

But i have no idea how to get the last and first surgery.

This is what I am looking to replicate using an example of R code:

```
Summarise <- DF%>%
                group_by(patient_id)%>%
                summarise(N_Surgery = n(),
                          First = surgery[which.min(date)],
                          Last = surgery[which.max(date)])
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Table:

[image]

Code:

```
Table 2 = 

ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[patient]),
    "Number of Surgeries", CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table')),
    "First Surgery", 
        VAR a = CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[date])) 
        RETURN CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[surgery]), 'Table'[date] = a),
    "Last Surgery", 
        VAR b = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[date])) 
        RETURN CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[surgery]), 'Table'[date] = b)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try with this 3 measure-

```
surgery_count = count('your_table_name'[patient])
```

```
surgery_first = 

var current_patient_min_date =
CALCULATE(
    MIN('your_table_name'[date]),
    ALLEXCEPT('your_table_name','your_table_name'[patient])
)

RETURN 
CALCULATE(
    MIN('your_table_name'[surgery]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT('your_table_name','your_table_name'[patient]),
        'your_table_name'[date] = current_patient_min_date
    )
)
```

```
surgery_last = 

var current_patient_max_date =
CALCULATE(
    MAX('your_table_name'[date]),
    ALLEXCEPT('your_table_name','your_table_name'[patient])
)

RETURN 
CALCULATE(
    MIN('your_table_name'[surgery]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT('your_table_name','your_table_name'[patient]),
        'your_table_name'[date] = current_patient_max_date
    )
)
```

Output-

[image]